# How to reload fetch data from CoreData in Widget iOS 14 when host App closes

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui, widgetkit

I'm currently developing an application using SwiftUI.

I want to reload data from `CoreData` in a `widget` to update newer data every when I close a host App.

But in my codes, the data doesn't get reloaded...

How could I solve that?

---

TimerApp.swift (Host APP)

```
import SwiftUI
import WidgetKit

@main
struct TimerApp: App {
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) private var scenePhase
    
    let persistenceController = PersistenceController.shared.managedObjectContext
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, persistenceController)
                .onChange(of: scenePhase) { newScenePhase in
                    if newScenePhase == .inactive {
                        WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

TimerWidget.swift(Widget Extension)

```
import WidgetKit
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct Provider: TimelineProvider {
    
    var moc = PersistenceController.shared.managedObjectContext
    var timerEntity:TimerEntity?
    
    init(context : NSManagedObjectContext) {
        self.moc = context
        let request = NSFetchRequest<TimerEntity>(entityName: "TimerEntity")
        
        do{
            let result = try moc.fetch(request)
            timerEntity = result.first
        }
        catch let error as NSError{
            print("Could not fetch.\(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }
    
    func placeholder(in context: Context) -> SimpleEntry {
        return SimpleEntry(date: Date(), timerEntity: timerEntity!)
    }
    
    func getSnapshot(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (SimpleEntry) -> ()) {
        let entry = SimpleEntry(date: Date(), timerEntity: timerEntity!)
        return completion(entry)
    }
    
    func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
        var entries: [SimpleEntry] = []
        
        let currentDate = Date()
        for hourOffset in 0 ..< 5 {
            let entryDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: hourOffset, to: currentDate)!
            let entry = SimpleEntry(date: entryDate, timerEntity: timerEntity!)
            entries.append(entry)
        }
        
        let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .atEnd)
        completion(timeline)
    }
}

struct SimpleEntry: TimelineEntry {
    let date: Date
    let timerEntity:TimerEntity
}

struct TimerWidgetEntryView : View {
        
    var entry: Provider.Entry
    
    var body: some View {
        return (
            VStack{
                Text(entry.timerEntity.task ?? "")
            }
        )
    }
}

@main
struct TimerWidget: Widget {
    let kind: String = "TimerWidget"
    
    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        StaticConfiguration(kind: kind, provider: Provider(context: PersistenceController.shared.managedObjectContext)) { entry in
            TimerWidgetEntryView(entry: entry)
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, PersistenceController.shared.managedObjectContext)
        }
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATED**

I updated my code to execute `NSFetchRequest` in the `getTimeline` function as well as below.

But in my code, when I build this project I have an error like below:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[TimerEntity task]:
> unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600003175400' terminating
> with uncaught exception of type NSException

```
struct Provider: TimelineProvider {
    
    var moc = PersistenceController.shared.managedObjectContext
    @State var timerEntity:TimerEntity?
    
    init(context : NSManagedObjectContext) {
        self.moc = context
        let request = NSFetchRequest<TimerEntity>(entityName: "TimerEntity")
        
        do{
            let result = try moc.fetch(request)
            timerEntity = result.first
        }
        catch let error as NSError{
            print("Could not fetch.\(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }
    
    func placeholder(in context: Context) -> SimpleEntry {
        return SimpleEntry(date: Date(), timerEntity: timerEntity ?? TimerEntity())
    }
    
    func getSnapshot(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (SimpleEntry) -> ()) {
        let entry = SimpleEntry(date: Date(), timerEntity: timerEntity!)
        return completion(entry)
    }
    
    func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
        var entries: [SimpleEntry] = []
        let currentDate = Date()
        
        let request = NSFetchRequest<TimerEntity>(entityName: "TimerEntity")
        do{
            let result = try moc.fetch(request)
            timerEntity = result.first
        }
        catch let error as NSError{
            print("Could not fetch.\(error.userInfo)")
        }
        
        for hourOffset in 0 ..< 5 {
            let entryDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: hourOffset, to: currentDate)!
            let entry = SimpleEntry(date: entryDate, timerEntity: timerEntity ?? TimerEntity())
            entries.append(entry)
        }
        
        let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .atEnd)
        completion(timeline)
    }
}
```

---

Xcode: Version 12.0.1

iOS: 14.0

Life Cycle: SwiftUI App

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code responsible for fetching data is only in `init`:

```
struct Provider: TimelineProvider {
    var moc = PersistenceController.shared.managedObjectContext
    var timerEntity:TimerEntity?
    
    init(context : NSManagedObjectContext) {
        self.moc = context
        let request = NSFetchRequest<TimerEntity>(entityName: "TimerEntity")
        
        do{
            let result = try moc.fetch(request)
            timerEntity = result.first
        }
        catch let error as NSError{
            print("Could not fetch.\(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

It is run only when the `Provider` is initialised. You need to execute this `NSFetchRequest` in the `getTimeline` function as well, so your `timerEntity` is updated.

---

Also, if you execute `WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()` every time `scenePhase` == `.inactive` it might be too often and your Widget might stop getting updated.

`inactive` is called whenever your app is moved from the background to the foreground (in both directions).

Try using `background` instead - this will be called only when your app is minimised or killed:

```
.onChange(of: scenePhase) { newScenePhase in
    if newScenePhase == .background {
        WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()
    }
}
```

Note: I'd recommend adding some safeguards around `WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()` to make sure to not refresh it *too often*.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, even though I change my code referring to your answer, the fetch data never updated... I can't see the data is updated even once.

Comment: Only when I build the project the data in `widget` get updated.

Comment: @Tio I updated my answer, basically you need to reload the `timerEntity` in the `getTimeline` as well (not only in init).

Comment: Thank you for updating your answer, I tried changing my code following your advice. But my code doesn't work and gets some error. I updated my question, would you mind advising me how should I change my code to execute `NSFetchRequest` in the `getTimeline` function as well?

Comment: Finally, I could reload data executing `NSFetchRequest` in the `getTimeline` function as well.